# TimeSpan Datatype in not getting correct time while exporting to Excel

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I've created a small project where I'm using TimeSpan Datatype and I am trying to get login and logout times, but when exporting to excel, the time is not displaying in the excel column.

Please help me.

This is the Code where I use timespan:

```
public TimeSpan PunchIn { get; set; }

[NotMapped]
public string Month
{
    get
    {
        var In = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(PunchDate.Date + PunchIn,
            TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(User.RegisteredTimeZone));
        return In.ToString("MMMM");
    }
}
```

And this is the kendo grid code:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
      .Name("TimeTrackingLogsGrid")
      .Columns(columns =>
      {
          columns.Bound(c => c.Id).Hidden(true).HtmlAttributes(new {style="text-align:center;"});
          columns.Bound(c => c.IsDeleted).Hidden(true);
          columns.Bound(c => c.ApprovalRequired).Visible((bool)ViewBag.IsAdmin).ClientTemplate("# if (ApprovalRequired == true && Approved == false && '"+ (ViewBag.IsAdmin).ToString() + "'=== 'True') {# Yes: <a data-ajax='true' data-ajax-complete='refreshGrid' data-ajax-method='POST' href='/Punch/Approve/#:Id#' class='grid-link' >Approve</a>#} else{# No #}#");
          columns.Bound(c => c.EmployeeName).Filterable(ftb => ftb.Multi(true).Search(true));
          columns.Bound(c => c.Month).Hidden(true).Filterable(ftb => ftb.Multi(true));
          columns.Bound(c => c.PunchDate)
              .ClientFooterTemplate("#= getFormattdDate(data.PunchDate.min) # - #= getFormattdDate(data.PunchDate.max) # ")
              .ClientGroupHeaderTemplate("#:convetUtcDateToLocalDate(PunchDate)#").HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "utc-date", utc_date_value = "#:PunchDate#" });
          columns.Bound(c => c.PunchInPic).Hidden(true).Visible((bool)ViewBag.IsAdmin).ClientTemplate("<img class='punchPic' width='100' src='data: image / png; base64,#:PunchInPic#'/>").HtmlAttributes(new { style="text-align:center;"});
          columns.Bound(c => c.PunchIn).Groupable(false).Filterable(false).ClientTemplate("#:PunchIn.Hours#:#:PunchIn.Minutes#").HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "utc-time", utc_time_value = "#:PunchIn.Hours#:#:PunchIn.Minutes#" });
          columns.Bound(c => c.PunchOutPic).Hidden(true).Visible((bool)ViewBag.IsAdmin).ClientTemplate("<img class='punchPic' width='100' src='data: image / png; base64,#:PunchOutPic#'/>").HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:center;" });
          columns.Bound(c => c.PunchOut).Groupable(false).Filterable(false).ClientTemplate("#:PunchOut == null ? 0 :PunchOut.Hours #:#: PunchOut == null ? 0 : PunchOut.Minutes  #").HtmlAttributes(new {@class= "utc-time", utc_time_value = "#: PunchOut == null ? 0 : PunchOut.Hours#:#:PunchOut == null ? 0 : PunchOut.Minutes #" });
          columns.Bound(c => c.Duration).Groupable(false).Filterable(false)
              .ClientFooterTemplate("#= SecondsToTime(data.DurationInSeconds.sum) # ")
              .ClientTemplate("#:formatDuration(Duration.Hours,Duration.Minutes) #").HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "" });
          columns.Bound(c => c.Comments).Visible((bool)ViewBag.IsAdmin).Filterable(false).Groupable(false).ClientTemplate("# if (ApprovalRequired == true && Approved == false && '" + (ViewBag.IsAdmin).ToString() + "' !== 'True') {# Please get this time log approved #} else{#<span class='comments' (#:Comments# == null ? '' : title='<ul>  #:Comments# </ul>')> view <span>#}#");
          columns.Command(command =>
          {
              //    command.Edit().Text(" ");
              command.Destroy().Text(" ");
          }).Width(50);
      })
      .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "full-screen-dashboard" })
      //.Scrollable()
      .Groupable()
      .Sortable()
      .Filterable()
      .Navigatable()
      .ColumnMenu()
      .ToolBar(toolbar => {
          //toolbar.Create();
          //toolbar.Save();
          toolbar.Pdf();
          toolbar.Excel();
          toolbar.Custom().Text("Clear Filter").HtmlAttributes(new { @class= "clearGridFilter"  });
      })

      .Excel(exl=>exl.AllPages(true).Filterable(true).FileName("Timesheet.xlsx")
          .ProxyURL(Url.Action("ExportSave", "Punch")))
```